# How to speed up Kinect Face Tracking at full depth resolution

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am working on application with Kinect and I need full depth resolution. Face tracking works fast (30 fps) with 320x240 depth resolution. But, when I switch to 640x480, I get one third of speed (~10fps). I have tried, to extract 320x240 depth image for face tracking (every second column and row), but I did not detect any face.

```
depthImageSmall = new short[this.depthImage.Length/4];
  for (int y = 0; y < 240; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 320; x++)
      depthImageSmall[y * 320 + x] = this.depthImage[y * 640 + x * 2];
```

How can I speed up face tracking?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the Kinect SDK for MS or OpenKinect?

Comment: MS Kinect SDK. I couldn't make work Kinect Face Tracking SDK with OpenNI v1.